# ng-touchstart and ng-touchend in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mousedown, mouseup, touchstart

I have an element which fires functions on `ng-mousedown` and `ng-mouseup`. However, It doesn't work on touch screen, is there any directive like `ng-touchstart` and `ng-touchend`?

Answer (score 14):

There is a module for this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch

But you can write your own directives for events too:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="plunker">
        <div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <div my-touchstart="touchStart()" my-touchend="touchEnd()">
                <span data-ng-hide="touched">Touch Me ;)</span>
                <span data-ng-show="touched">M-m-m</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
            app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.touched = false;

                $scope.touchStart = function() {
                    $scope.touched = true;
                }

                $scope.touchEnd = function() {
                    $scope.touched = false;
                }
            }]).directive('myTouchstart', [function() {
                return function(scope, element, attr) {

                    element.on('touchstart', function(event) {
                        scope.$apply(function() { 
                            scope.$eval(attr.myTouchstart); 
                        });
                    });
                };
            }]).directive('myTouchend', [function() {
                return function(scope, element, attr) {

                    element.on('touchend', function(event) {
                        scope.$apply(function() { 
                            scope.$eval(attr.myTouchend); 
                        });
                    });
                };
            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I installed this module yesterday and I wrote this post after. I will try with these directives.

Comment: Angular's ngTouch library does not support binding to individual touch and release events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985097/can-angulars-ngtouch-library-be-used-to-detect-a-long-click-touch-hold-release

Answer (score 8):

I have made those ealier today since I needed it myself:

- [ngTouch](https://github.com/marktopper/ngTouch) (a collection of the below)
- [ngTouchmove](https://github.com/marktopper/ngTouchmove)
- [ngTouchstart](https://github.com/marktopper/ngTouchstart)
- [ngTouchend](https://github.com/marktopper/ngTouchend)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I would like to use ngTouchstart, but unfortunately it uses eval(), which will break in a Chrome app.

Comment: thanks! can it decide moving left or right from the directive ?

Comment: @Matian2040, for that I would use [ngTouchstart](https://github.com/marktopper/ngTouchstart) and [ngTouchmove](https://github.com/marktopper/ngTouchmove) (or together with [ngTouch](https://github.com/marktopper/ngTouch)) library. Then save the coordinations for the `touchstart` event, and then on `touchmove` I would check the coordinates against the new event.

Comment: @MarkTopper where in the object are the touch coordinates stored?

Answer (score 2):

The version we came up with uses $parse(), which is what $eval() uses internally. We specifically wanted to handle mousedown and touchstart events using a single directive, but in the angular way so we can include angular style expressions.

Like so:

```
angular.module("ngStudentselect", []).directive('ngStudentselect', ['$parse', '$timeout', '$rootElement',
function($parse, $timeout, $rootElement) {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        var clickHandler = $parse(attr.ngStudentselect);

        element.on('mousedown touchstart', function(event) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                clickHandler(scope, {$event: event});
            });
        });
    };
}]);
```

This is a stripped down version of angular's ngClick directive.