# Cordova + AngularJS + Angular Material + Samsung Tab touch too accurate

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, touch, angular-material

Samsung Tab A 10 has a very precise touch screen which leads to, very often, not registering clicks. It's hard to say what causes it and where to try to make some enhancements, because there are many technologies involved. I know that touch start and touch end are being registered, but it seems that sometimes the difference in finger position between start and end event is big enough that it is not considered a click.

I thought about suppressing default events and write my own implementation, but the first step - suppressing doesn't really work for me.

Comment: Registering a click depends on the length of time that the finger is held static for - it needs to be held for 300ms. Moving the finger slightly during this time will create a drag rather than a click. The best solution is to bind the 'touchstart' event instead of the click event as touch start is triggered much more quickly

Comment: Yes, you're right. I guess I will need to make some kind of work around for angular ng-click or even deeper, whatever Angular Material uses, because it doesn't bother about any kind of touch prevention on document.

Comment: I sympathise as I started off using angular and hit this issue, unfortunately before I finished working round it I also hit real performance issues that caused me to abandon angular and move to plain jQuery (my app is a game with a timer so every second the view changes triggering a refresh, and angular 1 wasn't smart enough to do anything other than refresh the entire scope leading to layout thrashing). From memory I think that I used a custom directive along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170029/ng-touchstart-and-ng-touchend-in-angularjs